# How to create single Wix installer which will execute multiple msi/exe?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have created a Wix bootstrapper setup application, which installs two msi files from mentioned locations sequencially. The problem in this case is that, bootstrapper exe does not contain msi files inside it.

I want to create a single setup which consists of mutiple msi/exe setup files.
After executing the setup, it should first copy all the files including setup files to some folder and then execute copied setup files sequencially.

Comment: is your above mentioned issue was solved...?

Answer (score 1):

A WiX bootstrapper can do that. You are on the right track, you just need to add the Compressed="yes" attribute to your ExePackage and [MsiPackage](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msipackage.htm) elements.

The copying and executing is what the bootstrapper engine does behind the scenes. You don't need to do anything for that.

Comment: I have another query, My installer contains two msi files. In first msi, it prompts user for installation path. I wanted to install the second msi at the path specified while installing first msi. Is it possible to do it by using Wix. If yes, how?

Comment: You should make that another question to benefit/gain from others.